# Signalling condition variable in Java to trigger await

Tags: java, concurrency, triggers, locking

I created a *Runnable* class which periodically does some task. This class has a method to *trigger* immediate performance of a task discarding whether specified time has elapsed or not.

Class do perform periodic tasks in specified time but triggering does not work as expected.
Below is simplified class code with main method. According to API docs in my interpretation, when `trigger` is called, `await` is signaled and it has to return so that task is performed more or less *immediately* without waiting elapse of specified time.

What do I get wrong with Java locks and conditions? I could not figure out why my `trigger` method does not behave as expected?

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.*;

public class PeriodicRunner implements Runnable {

    private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private Condition cond = lock.newCondition();

    public void trigger() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            cond.signalAll();
        }
        finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            while(true) {
                cond.await(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                System.out.println("some task here");
            }
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        }
        finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        PeriodicRunner pr = new PeriodicRunner();
        new Thread(pr).start();
        pr.trigger();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use a `ScheduledExecutorService`?

Comment: This is a good choice, but it only schedules tasks. I wanted something that can be triggered at any time and pending task performed.

Comment: A `ScheduledExecutorService` can execute tasks immediately as well.  Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is here:

```
pr.trigger();
```

It is called before the new thread is actually started. So nobody receives first cond.signalAll(). Try changing it in this way:

```
Thread.sleep(100);
pr.trigger();
```

Comment: My God! Exactly it is! Also up-voting your answer. Now I don't know which answer to accept - you showed me what is wrong with my code, @SimonC provided a good alternative.

Comment: Choosing an answer to accept is quite simpler than Concurrency :)

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want could be achieved more transparently with a `ScheduledExecutorService`:

```
class PeriodicRunner implements Runnable
{
  private final ScheduledExecutorService _scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

  PeriodicRunner() 
  {
    _scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(this, 5, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  public void trigger()
  {
    _scheduler.execute(this);
  }

  public void run()
  {
    System.out.println("some task here");
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

For example, the following:

```
PeriodicRunner runner = new PeriodicRunner();
Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(12));
System.out.println("[" + new Date() + "] triggering extra task");
runner.trigger();    
Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1));
System.out.println("[" + new Date() + "] triggering extra task");
runner.trigger();
Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1));
System.out.println("[" + new Date() + "] triggering extra task");
runner.trigger();
```

Would produce the output:

```
[Wed Mar 20 13:18:31 CST 2013] some task here
[Wed Mar 20 13:18:36 CST 2013] some task here
[Wed Mar 20 13:18:38 CST 2013] triggering extra task
[Wed Mar 20 13:18:38 CST 2013] some task here
[Wed Mar 20 13:18:39 CST 2013] triggering extra task
[Wed Mar 20 13:18:39 CST 2013] some task here
[Wed Mar 20 13:18:40 CST 2013] triggering extra task
[Wed Mar 20 13:18:40 CST 2013] some task here
[Wed Mar 20 13:18:41 CST 2013] some task here
[Wed Mar 20 13:18:46 CST 2013] some task here
```

**UPDATE 2**

To expand on d3rzKy's answer, to fix your existing code, you could introduce a flag to indicate that `trigger` has been called.  Also, `await` isn't guaranteed to wait for the entire time, so you need to loop and keep track of how long you have already waited for.

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.*;

public class PeriodicRunner implements Runnable {

    private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private final Condition cond = lock.newCondition();

    private volatile boolean triggered = false;

    public void trigger() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            triggered = true;
            cond.signalAll();
        }
        finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            while(true) {

                if (!triggered) {
                    long remainingMs = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5);
                    long dueTimeMs = System.currentTimeMillis() + remainingMs;
                    while (remainingMs > 0 && !triggered) {
                        if (cond.await(remainingMs, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
                            break;
                        }
                        remainingMs = dueTimeMs - System.currentTimeMillis();
                    }
                }
                triggered = false;
                System.out.println("some task here");
            }
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        }
        finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        PeriodicRunner pr = new PeriodicRunner();
        new Thread(pr).start();
        pr.trigger();
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool, your code does what I wanted. Thanks! For now, I will just up-vote your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
new Thread(pr).start();
```

It will start `run` method and `lock` will be acquired for infinity.

```
pr.trigger();
```

When it calls `trigger` method, the `main` thread will wait infinitely cause `lock` has been acquired by another thread.

Comment: There is `await` of condition object in `run`, which releases its associated lock. So `lock` is not acquired for infinity.